# How do I import a private framework in xcode 7.3 for use in a Swift project?

Tags: xcode

I'm following this question:
[Handling private frameworks in Xcode ≥ 7.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37000053/handling-private-frameworks-in-xcode-%E2%89%A5-7-3)

But unsure how to dynamically link to a private framework in Swift, if it's even possible.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Never done that before, but have you tried importing the headers of the private framework in your Bridging Header file?

Comment: I've tried that but not having any luck.