# Implement MobileWIFI Private Framework in Xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, wifi, iphone-privateapi

I am creating  a private App in Xcode 7.3 ( iOS 9.3) , where I am going to utilize the WiFi Info.

I have Followed [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37000053/handling-private-frameworks-in-xcode-%E2%89%A5-7-3) , Bluetooth Private Framework works fine However:

I am trying to implement Private Framework "`MobileWIFI.Framework`" in XCode 7.3 , but it gives me this error:

> "_WiFiManagerClientCopyNetworks", referenced from: -
>
> [AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in
>   AppDelegate.o "_WiFiManagerClientCreate", referenced from:
>   -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in AppDelegate.o
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I tried with using `mobilewifi.framework` files of iOS version 9.3, 8.1, 7 
It gives same error.

I think the headers are not matching the `.tbd` file of Framework

Comment: Please show the **code** that you are using, not just the error message. In other words, the code you wrote in your `[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]` method, which I'm assuming tries to use `_WiFiManagerClientCopyNetworks()`.

Comment: var manager = WiFiManagerClientCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0)
var networks = WiFiManagerClientCopyNetworks(manager)
print("networks: \(networks)")
CFRelease(manager)
CFRelease(networks)

Comment: Did you add [these headers](https://github.com/Cykey/ios-reversed-headers/tree/master/MobileWiFi) to your project?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: Are you getting classes with `NSClassFromString`? You can't use the class symbols directly.