# iOS 10 Toggle On/Off programmatically 3G/4G data with Private API

Tags: objective-c, swift, ios10, iphone-privateapi

So I got a client asking for a way to programmatically reset the data connection of his iPhone. The app won't go to the Appstore so any help is welcome.

There is two possibility but each one does involve Private API uses :
• Toggle 3G/4G On/Off
• Toggle AirPlane mode On/Off

The question is simple :
How to use the Private API to get the wanted result ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With probability of 95% you won't be able to do that. Apple closed most of private APIs as of iOS 8.4. For education purposes, you could take a look at the [iOS runtime headers](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers) for iOS 10.1 just to see what's no longer available.

Moreover, as of Xcode 7 you can't even [link the private frameworks inside an app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37001091/1313939) that easily - be it for AppStore or AdHoc.

So even if the client device is using a jailbreak, you won't be able to achieve it.

What you could do though - is write a jailbreak tweak and post it to Cydia, or somehow call an existing preinstalled tweak from inside your app on a jailbroken device - though I've never heard anyone do that.